# Identify this South African spider

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

A family member saw this spider in her garden in the Cape Town area of South Africa. It's very attractive and I wondered what species it was?

[image: Spider]

Approx size is that it would fit roughly on a 3cm diameter circle.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit] your post to include the size this spider. This can be helpful for narrowing down possible species.  Thanks! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the location and image you provided, I suspect this spider to be Garden Orb-Weaver, belonging to the spider family Araneidae.

Just a side note: I used an app called iNaturalist to identify this spider. It is a helpful app to identify insects and plants.

Here is a similar image I found online:
[image]